# Dead links on events, donations, pretty much anything I create

Tags: wordpress, civievent, civicontribute

I'm in the middle of an install and stuck on a couple issues.

I've been all over this StackExchange yet I can't seem to make basic CivicCRM links work in a couple of sections in the site I'm trying to deploy.

- CiviCRM 5.27.0 running on Wordpress 5.4.2 on top of Ubuntu
- Yes, my WP permalinks is set to "post name"
- yes, I have an .htaccess and it looks like this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

- yes, Apache is set up to obey that .htaccess for this site
- yes, my Administer -> System Settings -> CMS Database Integration is set, and it's set to https://crm.[siteiamdeploying].org/civicrm/
- yes https://crm.[siteiamdeploying].org/civicrm/ is a page that exists and loads

... yet when I do things like:

a) Create an event, flesh out its details and see links like
TEST: https://crm.[siteiamdeploying].org/event/register/?reset=1&action=preview&id=98
LIVE: https://crm.[siteiamdeploying].org/civicrm/event/register/?reset=1&id=98

Or, for example, set up a DONATE page and then attempt to load that page by doing

Civicrm-> manage contribution pages -> set up a contribution page ->

... then use that pages "links -> Live page" or "links -> Test page" links to try and load those pages, i.e.

https://crm.[siteiamdeploying].org/civicrm/contribute/transact/?reset=1&id=4

... all I get on those links is the default WordPress "not found" page, i.e.

"Oops! That page can’t be found.
It looks like nothing was found at this location. Maybe try a search?"

And I can see these  404'ing/ erroring out in the Apache access logs like this

67.160.XX.XX - - [06/Oct/2020:02:15:54 +0000] "GET /civicrm/contribute/transact/?reset=1&id=4 HTTP/1.1" 404 60939 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:81.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/81.0"

Can somebody point me in the right direction and/or towards sensible debug logs or processes before I start throwing heavy things at my monitor?

Comment: I cross posted in https://chat.civicrm.org/civicrm/channels/wordpress. You may want to join there if you don't get a response here soon.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have CMS integration set in your system? You need to have default page or post in WordPress and have it set in CMS integration

Comment: @bhance In addition to this, try visiting your "Permalinks" settings page and saving again. This refreshes the WordPress Rewrite Rules.

Comment: @pradeep yes, my Administer -> System Settings -> CMS Database Integration is set, and it's set to https://crm.[siteiamdeploying].org/civicrm/ and that page loads.

Comment: I think I've solved this. All the documentation I was reading here was saying "Set permalinks to "postname". In Wordpress, I was choosing " Post name  https://crm.[redacted].org/sample-post/ ..... and not the one below it, saying, "Custom Structure  https://crm.[redacted].org" /%postname%/  -- changing that seems to have made all my pages start loading.

Comment: maybe add this as your own Answer